# I wish to create a website that gives alerts to drink water every n hours, how do I get an alert to show even if the user were to switch tabs?

Tags: javascript, html

following is the method that I tried to test, but the main problem I faced is that if the tabs are switched the alerts no longer appear and the queued alerts appear all together if the tab is reopened.

```
$(".button5sec").click(function()
{
  setInterval(function(){alert("drink water bro!")}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This won't work.

Comment: You can only do this through a full-fledged application

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You potentially can use Desktop notification API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Something like this should work

```js
function showNotification() {
  const notification = new Notification("Drink water", {
    body: "Don't forget to drink water"
  })
}

if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
} else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission();
}

$(".button5sec").click(function()
{
  setInterval(function(){showNotification()}, 5000);
});
```